# using Override UICollectionView to call delegate methods on UicollectionViewController

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have `UICollectionViewController` with all the `dataSource` and delegate methods behaving correctly. Recently I added Flip View on every cell when I select and when I select another cell the first cell get deselected using protocol methods correctly.

1. Now I have a scenario where once I select the cell and then it gets flipped. User perform segue thru' button on flipView
2. When I return back that cell is still selected but when I select another cell the didDeselect never gets called from collectionView on 1st one.

Answer

1) I implemented custom UICollectionView and added below code since I am doing some animations in controller I have to call it this way

```
// Little hack to call Controllers method to delesect the cell
- (void)deselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"Programmtically cell-deselected %@", indexPath);
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[self cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selected = NO;
   [self.delegate collectionView:self didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   [super deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:animated]; //Not required!?
}
```

2) And In main controller when user performs segueu on already selected cell I do this

```
[self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Is this right way to do it? This works fine and I see no issue. May be I could have called collectionView:self didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] from within contoller itself (in segue) but somehow I didnt like that as the calls becomes totally confusing to read.

```
[self collectionView:self.collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```